# BackRequested is triggering more than once in UWP app

Tags: webview, uwp, back-button, back-button-control

I have an app in which i mainly have a webview. i am having a problem. i have made the back button to goto previous webpage of webview it works fine and when it has no previous pages it quits with a MessageBox(Popup). The problem is when i navigate another page and press back it recursively triggers back button event and shows the MessageBox

```
 Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (Web_view.CanGoBack)
            {
                Web_view.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
           else
            {
                quit();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };
```

The above is code of my main page

```
 private async void quit()
    {
        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Do you really want to quit?", "Quit");
        msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes") { Id = 0 });
        msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No") { Id = 1 });
        var ans = await msg.ShowAsync();
        if(ans.Id.Equals(0))
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exit");
            App.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

this is the code of quit function.
I am navigating to another page from this using code

```
 private void about_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }
```

And the backRequested code of blanckPage1 is

```
 SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s,e)=>
        {
            e.Handled = true;
           // Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= BlankPage1_BackRequested;
           //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BackRequested");
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                Frame.GoBack();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };
```

To make it more clear for example when i open the app the webview navigates to www.example.com then following the links there i will get to some other page(for example www.example.com/link/firstlink). then i will navigate my frame to blankpage1 and from there i will press back. then insted of coming back to previous page (www.example.com/link/firstlink) it comes to beginning page (www.example.com) and shows the quit popup how can i fix this?

Thank you for all your replay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are still keeping the event handler: In your code when navigating back from BlankPage1, both .BackRequested handlers are called. You would need to deregister from .BackRequested on MainPage when leaving it, for example like this:

MainPage:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested -= OnBackRequested;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
    // Your code to navigate back
    if (Web_view.CanGoBack)
    {
        Web_view.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        quit();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

And the same on BlankPage1... Though it would be far easier to register to `BackRequested` in your App.xaml.cs where you would handle your `(Window.Current.Content as Frame)` for the whole app, something like this. To make it "nice" code also with an interface:

INavigationPage:

```
public interface INavigationPage {
    // When overriding the method returns true or false if the Page handled back request
    bool HandleBackRequested();
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
// ... Code before
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (frame == null) return;

    INavigationPage page = frame.Content as INavigationPage;
    if (page == null) return;

    // Ask if the page handles the back request
    if (page.HandleBackRequested()) {
        e.Handled = true;
    // If not, go back in frame
    } else if (frame.CanGoBack) {
        e.Handled = true;
        frame.GoBack();
    }
}
// ... Code after
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
... class MainPage : Page, INavigationPage {
    // ... Code before

    // Implement the interface handling the backRequest here if possible
    public bool HandleBackRequested() {
        if (Web_view.CanGoBack) {
            Web_view.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // ... Code after
}
```

Then the BlankPage does not require any code and no subscribing to .BackRequested.